# Fragment loses activity reference when navigated to a second timet

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, drawerlayout

I use DrawerLayout and navController to navigate with fragments, in a single activity app. However, when I go to any of the fragments for the second time, I lose my reference to the main activity when I call the getActivity() method (returns null).

This is how i initiate navigation in main activity:

```
private fun initNavigation(){
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)


        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController, drawerLayout)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController)

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            navController.graph
        ).setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build()



        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
            when(destination.id){
               R.id.searchFragment->  { supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon)
               setTitleTop("Home")}
                R.id.historyFragment-> setTitleTop("History")
                R.id.myCollectionFragment -> setTitleTop("My Collection")
                R.id.settingsFragment-> setTitleTop("Settings")
                R.id.infoFragment-> setTitleTop("Details")

            }

        }

    }
```

And this is how I navigate from activity:

```
 override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_home -> {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
                    .navigate(R.id.searchFragment)
            }
            R.id.nav_my_collection -> {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
                    .navigate(R.id.myCollectionFragment)

            }
            R.id.nav_wishlist -> {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
                    .navigate(R.id.wishlistFragment)


            }
            R.id.nav_history -> {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
                    .navigate(R.id.historyFragment)
            }
            R.id.nav_settings->{
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
                    .navigate(R.id.settingsFragment)

            }
        }
        item.isChecked = true
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
```

When I navigate to the same fragment for the second time, my activity (or getActivity()) is null. I noticed the problem when I tried to use navController from my fragment:

```
      override fun onRecordClicked(position: Int) {
        val bundle = Bundle().also {
            it.putSerializable(InfoFragment.RECORD_PARAM, viewModel.recordAdapter.records[position].record)
        }


        activity?.let {
            Navigation.findNavController(it, R.id.fragment)
                .navigate(R.id.infoFragment, bundle)
        }
        

    }
```

To solve this I implemented the following in my fragment:

```
   lateinit var homeActivity : HomeActivity

   override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if(context is HomeActivity)
            homeActivity = context
    }
```

And then used this reference to navigate:

```
        homeActivity.let {
            Navigation.findNavController(it,R.id.fragment)
                .navigate(R.id.infoFragment, bundle)
        }
```

Even though I solved it in this, not so smart way, I would like to understand why this happens? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Some possibilities: more than one fragment instance and the one where `onRecordClicked` fires is no longer attached to an activity. Or `onRecordClicked` just fires outside onAttach/onDetach of fragment lifecycle. Capturing an activity reference like you have as a workaround is not recommended as it could be leaking the activity.

Comment: @laalto Thank you for your reply. The onRecordClicked() function is being called from a recyclerview's View. The fragment's onCreate() is being ran every time when navigating, so a new instance every time. It could be that RecyclerViews lifecycle is outside of onAttach(), but I lack the knowledge to diagnose this problem. One interesting thing is that this error doesn't happen in the starting Fragment, but does in every other. How would you recommend I move further? Would a github link in PM provide any additional context, if you're willing to take a look? Cheers!